Вопрос про часовые пояса и UTC
Что-то я нигде не могу найти конкретный ответ на не очень конкретный вопрос.
Я понимаю, что такое UTC - это время по Гринвичу - нулевой меридиан, причем он не подвергается никаким летним/зимним переводам времени и так далее.
Все источники говорят о том, что нужно работать и сохранять время в UTC, что как бы логично.
Но есть один нюанс.
К примеру, начало и конец события привязаны к локальному времени, так как весь ресторанный бизнес работает по локальному времени. Да и учеба тоже. Обычно когда переводят время на летнее/зимнее никто расписание не меняет (кроме животноводства)
И вот, рассмотрим 2 варианта:
1) Если храним время начала мероприятия в локальном времени - мы должны постоянно проверять локальное время с сохраненным, потому как просто таймер поставить невозможно - программа не знает когда в будущем будет переход на зимнее/летнее время.
Тип проверки: сравнение времен в каждом цикле программы. Недостаток: можно получить ошибку при переносе программы в другую локацию.
2) Если храним время начала мероприятия в UTC, который был сформирован при текущем зимнем времени (можно использовать и сравнение в каждом цикле и таймер), то если на момент начала мероприятия уже будет летнее время - будет смещение.
Тип проверки: сравнение времен в каждом цикле программы / отсчет таймера в каждом цикле программы. Недостаток: можно получить смещение при переходе на летнее/зимнее время.
В итоге вопрос: нужно хранить и время и именно название часового пояса (никакие там offset) ?
Это такой уточняющий вопрос. Просто я прочитал чью-то работу и мне показалось, что там все таки толком не уточнили, каким же образом требуется правильно сохранять время.
Потому что выражение "в локальном времени + оффсэт" - не говорит вообще ни о чем. На одном меридиане может быть несколько государств, со своими правилами перехода на летнее/зимнее время.

Все базы данных сохраняют только Timestamp который базируется на настройке самой базы данных. А что если у меня в базе хранятся разные времена для разных поясов?
Если все-таки хранение смещения по меридиану не спасает от всяких "хотелок" отдельных стран, которые могут смещать время как угодно им вздумается - то каким образом происходит точное хранение таких правил, и кто гарантирует, что с момента записи таких данных - не произойдет изменение внутри этих правил?

Наверное я просто зануда и любой скажет "что ты прикопался к 1 часу". Но возникает вопрос - а как же банковская система? Договора, юристы, иски, какие тогда временные метки ставят в серьезных договорах, где 1 час все-таки решает многое?
Просто конкретно меня это волнует по той причине, что я пытаюсь выяснить "паттерн" по которому эта проблема решается. И соответствовать этому паттерну, чтобы быть в синхроне с другими программами. Чтобы поведение программы было прогнозируемым и так далее.

всё таки время в будущем хранится уже с учётом летнего времени. Хотя это не очень поможет если правительство внезапно (привет Казахстан) решит поменять часовые пояса. Универсального решения нет, у разных событий разная привязка ко времени, магазин будет открываться в 8 утра по текущему часовому поясу, а солнечное затмение состоится в абсолютный момент времени и никакие переводы часов на него не влияют.

В общем да, время это сложно, а время в будущем это вообще ужас.

@AlexeyTen , я поэтому и написал - что в локальном времени нужно всегда сравнивать, а не ставить таймер на конкретную длительность. По моему нет смысла рассчитывать наперед. Если нужно узнать сколько времени это займет  между двумя локальными датами - тогда нужно вызывать отдельную функцию которая принимает обе даты и учитывает оффсэт для каждой даты отдельно, как будто бы этот оффсэт  запрашивался в тот момент о котором говорят эти две даты.

Меня всегда напрягает метод типа "addMonth" - эта проблема похожа на проблему с высокосностью года/месяца и лето/зима перехода. Непонятно что именно оно добавляет. 30 дней или до схожей даты. Выносит мозг!!! Как можно добавлять месяцы, если они не имеют стабильной длины? Максимум неделю. Но самое смешное что addWeek нету в DateTime, к примеру))
